# Forward and backward stepwise selection in Stata

Tags: stata

Is there a command to that does both forward and backward selection in Stata? From what I can tell `stepwise` will only do one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?stepwise for a start on the documentation.

Specify both `pr()` and `pe()` if you want flexibility to move in both directions. Whether this is exactly what you want I don't know.